# Rename all files in folder with arguments?

Tags: powershell, cmd, rename

I have a folder with video files as such :

***Anime Episode (1).mp4 , AnimeEpisode (2).mp4 , Anime Episode (3).mp4 , ...***

I need to rename them as follows :

***Anime Episode 1.mp4 , Anime Episode 2.mp4 , Anime Episode 3.mp4 , ...***

I need to drop only the brackets but keep everything else. Is there a Powershell script or CMD command I can use to make this happen? Please help, I can't rename all 1000+ episodes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp4 | % { Move-Item $_ $($_ -replace '[()]','') }
```

This uses a regex to replace the brackets

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work with some test files i copied and tried on. But I'm worried it might scramble the order of the files though (because I don't understand the code). But it didn't scramble the test files so I guess that's fine. Have you used this before?

Comment: It will only remove the brackets, the order depends on how you've ordered them I would think! This will apply to all `.mp4` files is the only thing, use `Anime*.mp4` if you don't want to target all mp4s in the dir.

Comment: I'm trying out a few variations right now. Because I need to sometimes specify string literals to remove. For example "Watch Anime Online". Do you know if I can put them inside the [ ] brackets?

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61007401/edit) to include this info, otherwise you will get incomplete or unsuitable answers. The answer I've provided will only remove brackets, because that's what you asked! It is possible to extend to cover your use case.

Comment: Sorry, the actual question was the original intention, but then the need expanded. So I just decided to try out some variation and understand the code so I can modify it. Good news though, it worked like a charm. Both, your answer AND the one given by @ManhND. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming filenames are splitted by comma with no space)

```
Set-Location "Filepath"
$args[0].split(",") | ForEach {
  Rename-Item -Path "$_" -Newname {$_.tostring().replace('(','').replace(')','')}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd your folder location
ls *.mp4 | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "\)|\(",""}
```

you can specify string you want to replace in `-replace "\)|\(","".`

1. first argument: ")|(" is what you want to replace. This mean ) or (, but this special characters so you need to escape by add \
2. second argument: "" is what you want to replace to. Because you want to remove () so just let it null.

Comment: can i specify string literals in there too? for eample

ls *.mp4 | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "\)|\( hello",""}

Comment: yes you can specify like that to match your file name, but dont forget escape special character

Comment: and you can limit what file you want to rename by ls command. example ls AnimeA*.mp4 | ..... this will rename file start with AnimeA and end with mp4